# How to write this constraint in an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization

Let $x_i$ be a binary variable in the set $\{0,1\}$ for all $i$ in the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, i.e., $x_i\in\{0,1\},\,\forall\,i\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$.

I would like to write the constraint:

$$\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{i=1\\
                  x_i\neq0}}^nA_ix_i>A,$$
where $A_i$ and $A$ are given as inputs.

Comment: What do you mean you want to write the constraint? you already have.

Comment: I mean how to write it in a solver for example. The subscript $x_i\neq0$ makes it difficult for me to write it.

Comment: There are different issues: first the constraint is not linear, second constraints with $<$ or $>$ signs are never used in optimization. The  $x_i\neq 0$ should not be a problem. What solver are you using?

Comment: I would like to use cplex solver.

Comment: do you need a linear form for your model?

Comment: you can write $x_i \neq 0$ with an if condition, something like: for all $i$ in $1,…,n$, if $x_i \neq 0$...

Comment: Thanks. I thought about applying the log function.

Comment: Yes that is an idea to transform a product into a sum, although it will remain non linear.

Comment: Do you know how to linearize that product?